How to permanently store an integer variable in C without using constant?
So the problem is that I have an integer, but I need to reuse this a lot and it would be a mess if I call a different function to do different mathematical operation (Luhn's Alogrithem). So is there a way to do that?
while(num != 0)
{
    array[length] = (num % 10);
    num = num/10;      //here its clear that number will become 0
    length --;  
}

int secondArrayLength = 0;

for( int secondlength = countDigits(num) - 1; secondlength > 0; secondlength = secondlength - 2)
{
    if (array[secondlength] > 0)
    {
        secondArrayLength ++;
    }
}

So its clear in the code that by doing the num = num/10 I will eventually get zero. This is then unusable in the for( int secondlength = countDigits(num) - 1.
Is there a way around this without the need to declare another variable to temporary store number?
(edit: number is asked by a user so I can not declare it as a constant)

You can't change a variable and have it remain the same... why can't you just use a second variable to hold the original value?

Is that the only approach to it? I've seen somewhere that you can use a cache to store it..? Or rather am I wrong? Also because there are many more operations with number I don't want to declare another variable each time I do one.

This is all pretty vague. Specific examples in the form of complete functions would be more helpful.

The question is more like how can u store a variable without storing a variable? u cant!

"don't want to declare another variable each time I do [a different operation]" Every time a variable is passed as a parameter to a function, it is passed "by value", meaning a copy of the value is made for use by the function. This is how programs work. Your "wants" and "don't wants" are irrelevant. Suggest you set those aside until you have acquired some experience.

OR... Having decomposed the value into each of its digits, all you need to do is reassemble the value from those digits putting it back into that one variable (using ANOTHER loop)... This would truly indicate to the reader that the code was written by a beginner... :-)

Yeah realised halfway that it is asking magic to happen. This was a stupid post but thanks for all the help.

I am quite a beginner, just started using C so please bare with me.

This question should be closed. It falls in the category of: "I want my cake whole, and I want to eat it, too!"... The wisdom of the ages clearly states, "You can't!" Please delete this question yourself. It serves no purpose keeping it around...

@GhostaNero It's not clear what your problem is. Is it performance? Is it readability of the code?

PS: Luhn's Algorithm - It IS possible to perform ALL the required operations on a long long representation of a CC number with only ONE pass through all the digits... Set yourself the goal of working out how to do that over the coming months. Do not attempt this until you've acquired a lot more understanding, experience and confidence...

C has no "magic" that can/will make the value of num after the while the same as the value before the while loop.
You need to write code so that it happens. And that can be done in several ways.
1: Use a function
Putting the while loop code into a function is the closest you get to the desired "magic" behavior. In reality there is no "magic". Behind you back a copy of num will be made.
Anyway - If you pass num to a function then the changes made to num inside the function will not change num in the caller code. For instance:
int doX(int num, int length, int array[])
{
    while(num != 0)
    {
        array[length] = (num % 10);
        num = num/10;      //here its clear that number will become 0
        length--;  
    }
    return length;
}

and then do:
length = doX(num, length, array);

int secondArrayLength = 0;

for( int secondlength = countDigits(num) - 1; secondlength > 0; secondlength = secondlength - 2)
{
    if (array[secondlength] > 0)
    {
        secondArrayLength ++;
    }
}

A variant would be to pass length as a pointer so that it can be changed in the function, i.e. then the return and assignment could be removed.
(notice: The changes made to the array by the function will be remain when the function returns. Arrays are handled different than e.g. plain integers).
2: Use save and restore
Use an extra variable to save the value of num before the loop and restore it after the loop.
saved_num = num;
while(num != 0)
{
    ...
}
num = saved_num;

int secondArrayLength = 0;

...

A variant of this solution is to make the while loop code operate on saved_num instead of num. Then you don't need the restore part as num isn't changed. Or as suggested by user Fe2O3 you could implement this variant as a for loop like the below:
for (int x = num; x != 0; x = x / 10)
{
    array[length] = x % 10;
    length--;  
}


For the OP to see and consider the disadvantages of approaching a problem with prejudices about how it should be solved...
Using only a 6 digit value, the following provides a "sketch" of how one might begin to code two steps of Luhn's Algorithm while avoiding using a copy of the initial variable and deliberately avoiding writing/using helper functions.
int main( void ) {
    int n = 732516;

    int sumOdd  = 0;
    // NB: This does NOT "double and sum digits of product" as required by Luhn
    sumOdd  += n /     10 % 10; // the 1
    sumOdd  += n /   1000 % 10; // the 2
    sumOdd  += n / 100000 % 10; // the 7
    // not shown: 5 more lines to make up 8 of 16 digits of a CC number
    // value of n is unchanged

    int sumEven = 0;
    sumEven += n /     1 % 10; // the 6
    sumEven += n /   100 % 10; // the 5
    sumEven += n / 10000 % 10; // the 3
    // not shown: 5 more lines to make up other 8 of 16 digits of a CC number
    // value of n remains unchanged

    return 0;
}

The bloat, complexity and fallibility of coding like this should be self-evident.
No need to point out that a single sum variable would suffice.
